# OOP: How do I decide which methods to outsource and which type to use?

Tags: php, oop

**What do I want to do:** I want to build a WebScraper for different pages (webpageA, webpageB). I want to read the title and the teaser image. Since both pages use different tags to display the title, I have two patterns.

**My goal:** I want to try out the principle of inheritance on a practical example to understand it.

**What have I done so far:** My controller receives a request with a url. The controller checks whether the URL belongs to the page webpageA or webpageB. Now it dynamically creates an instance of the corresponding service: `$service = new WebpageService[A || B]($url)`. Then I start the scraping with `$service->startScraping()`.

Both services implement an interface in which I have the signatures `getTitle()` and `getImage()`.

```php
class WebpageAService implements IPageService

    private string $url;
    private array $data;

    private $keyMap = [
      'key' => 'mappendKey',
       ....
    ];
  
   public function __construct($url) {
     $this->url = $url;
   }

    public function startScraping() {
      $this->data = // getTheDataFromApi()
      return [
        'title' => $this->getTitle(),
        'image' => $this->getImage()
      ]
    }

    public function getTitle(): string
    {
        $key = 'title';
        if (! $this->keyExists($key)) {
            return "Please enter a $key";
        }

        return $this->getValue($key);
    }

    private function keyExists(string $key): bool
    {
        if (! isset($this->data[$this->keyMap[$key]])) {
            $this->errorLog[$key] = "Error: $key with the mapped key: $this->keyMap[$key] not found on $this->url";

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function getValue(string $key): string
    {
        return strlen($this->data[$this->keyMap[$key]]) > 0 ? 
            $this->data[$this->keyMap[$key]] : $this->message['length'];
    }
}
```

**My question:** Can I outsource the two private functions? So that I don't have to include them for each webpage[A || B] class? If so, would a trait make sense here? I am very grateful for your hints and comments. Thanks for your time! Max

Comment: If the code is the same for all classes, put it in the parent class that they all inherit from. Make it `protected` rather than `private` and the subclasses can use it.

Comment: @Barmar WebpageAService has no parent class. It only implements some signatures. Do I have a wrong assumption here?

Comment: Pull out the common code into a separate class, and make these subclasses of it.

Comment: @Barmer Ok. I hope that I now understood your Comment. I have to create new parent Class names e.g. PageService. Then i edit my child to: `class WebpageAService extends PageService implements IPageService`. In the parent i will put the functions which i use in every childClass. One more Question: it will be good if i implement the interface in the parent?

Comment: Yes, since the implementation is in the parent class. Subclasses inherit the parent class's `implements`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. I have just learned and understood something important. Thank you very much!  :-)

Comment: @MaxPattern Once you get everything working, for educational purposes you can try making a version where you use an abstract class instead of an interface. They work similar, but you can have non-abstract methods in your parent. Not saying it's a better way than what you are doing, just offering an excuse to experiment.

Comment: @CMiller Good morning and thank you for your suggestion :-)  To be honest, I was thinking about doing it yesterday but I was wondering what the advantage would be and when to choose an abstract class over an Implemented class.

Comment: @MaxPattern It's very subjective and not something easy to pin down to a simple rule. But something to consider is that you can only have one abstract class to be a parent, while you can have many interfaces implemented on a class. An Abstract class though can have working functions while an interface cannot. I think there are too many variables for there to be an easy answer. But it may come down to you liking one over the other.